# How to store date only value from CalendarDatePicker to SQLite database in Windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app, datetimeoffset, windows-10-universal

In my Windows 10 universal app i use the CalendarDatePicker to select a date:

```
<CalendarDatePicker x:Name="cdpStartDate" Width="150" />
```

In Code behind i use the following code to store the date to a SQLite database:

```
booking = new Bookings();
using (
     SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn =
        new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), Common.Utils.DbPath()))
        {
        booking.StartDate = cdpStartDate.Date.ToDateTime();
        conn.Update(booking);
        }
```

My table class looks like this:

```
[Table("Bookings")]
public class Bookings
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int BookingId { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

While debugging the value for booking.StartDate is 18.11.2015 00:00:00. But after saving the value to the SQLite database the value is converted to 17.11.2015 23:00:00. This seems to be Utc time.
I do not need any time information in my app, just the Date only.

How can i save the date without conversion to my database?

Thanks,
Uwe

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps are usually just the 0:00 time of a certain day. As SQLite doesn't take care of timezones for you, if you want to get a pure date out, you have to put a pure (without timezone) datetime in.

Try:

```
booking.StartDate = cdpStartDate.Date.ToDateTime().ToUniversalTime().Date;
```

It's actually the DateTime class, that is so *friendly* to add your local timezone information to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
GeographicRegion userRegion = new GeographicRegion();
string regionCode = userRegion.Code;

Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatter("shortdate", new[] { regionCode }, regionCode, CalendarIdentifiers.Gregorian, ClockIdentifiers.TwentyFourHour);

DateTimeOffset result = cdpStartDate.Date ?? DateTimeOffset.MinValue;

string shortDate = dtf.Format(result);
```

I used the above to create a custom short date formatter based on the local windows regional settings and then store that to a string. I know you wanted to store a date, but as Kai said, SQL doesn't store Dates without the time part so this will give just the date in short format.